# Discord.js v14 how make bot changing status on interval

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm making my discord bot in version 14 and I'm trying to make the discord bot change its status for example every 10s, but I can't program it and figure out how to do it, I'm attaching my entire code here, I need some advice on how to do it.

I'm just discovering the new version of discord.js, I'm used to old systems

```
const Event = require('../../structures/EventClass');

const { ActivityType } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = class ReadyEvent extends Event {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            name: 'ready',
            once: true,
        });
    }
    async run() {
        const client = this.client;

        client.user.setActivity(' TEST BOT WORKS', { type: ActivityType.Playing });

        console.log("✅ [READY!] Starting Discord Bot...")
        console.log(`✅ [ONLINE!] Discord Bot is now online with ${client.users.cache.size} users and ${client.guilds.cache.size} servers.`);
    }
};
```

So that the status of the discord bot changes every 10 seconds

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap your `client.user.setActivity()` in a [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) timer. For example, this is how you could change the status every 60 seconds with a random status taken from an array:

```js
const customStatus = [" TEST BOT WORKS", "Status 1", "Status 2", "Status 3", "Status 100"];
setInterval(() => {
    client.user.setActivity(customStatus[Math.floor(Math.random() * customStatus.length)], {
        type: ActivityType.Playing
    });
}, 60000);
```

This is an example and should help you understand how timers work and how you could change the status every x seconds once your bot has started.

`!` **Note:** I wouldn't change your status under 60 seconds as it rapidly results in rate limits.